# Flatten function in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

**Problem defining the NN architecture**

I'm trying to create a CNN with Keras for the CIFAR-10 image dataset (https://keras.io/datasets/), but I can't get the Flatten function to work even though it appears in the Keras library: https://keras.io/layers/core/#flatten

Here is the error message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-aabd6bce9082> in <module>()
     12 nn.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
     13 nn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
---> 14 nn.add(Flatten())
     15 nn.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
     16 nn.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

NameError: name 'Flatten' is not defined
```

I'm using Jupyter running Python 2.7 and Keras 1.1.1. Below is the code for the NN:

```
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

nn = Sequential()
nn.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))

# Max-pool reduces the size of inputs, by taking the largest pixel-value from a grid
nn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
nn.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
nn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
nn.add(Flatten())
nn.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
nn.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

Thanks in advance,

-Johan B.

Comment: In general, if an error comes back with a phrase along the lines of "is not defined" or "has no attribute" your probably missing an import or using old versions of some library.

Answer (score 5):

try to import the layer first:

```
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten

nn = Sequential()
nn.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))

# Max-pool reduces the size of inputs, by taking the largest pixel-value from a grid
nn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
nn.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
nn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
nn.add(Flatten())
nn.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
nn.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: Thanks Paddy! That helps, but I get a different mistake now related to the Flatten function: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pack'

Comment: I recommend you to upgrade keras and tensorflow (or theano), because you are using quite old version of Keras

Comment: Thanks again for your help. For our projects, the external server runs Keras 1.1.1, but I'll try to test the code on a updated version.